# Working with photos in ElementaryOS

Tags: pantheon-files, photos, file-management

Elementary OS uses Photos to open pictures, but this has quite a couple of basic problems:

- <del>[Ctrl + S does not work for Viewer edits](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-photos/+bug/1405890)</del>
- [Sorting of images is inconsistent with order in Files](https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues/14)
- <del>[Does not support GIF files](https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues/50)</del> (it does now, although not animating ones yet)
- [Can't delete files from disk](https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues/44) (Delete photos in Photo Viewer like EOG)
- <del>Navigation (next prev) takes a while to enable when opening a photo (Opening a photo, very slow navigation between them)</del>
- <del>[Can't slide fast through photos using arrows, otherwise I'd get a full screen window](https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues/104)</del>

All these things are known bugs, but most get a low priority.

At the same time Files doesn't allow setting another previewer: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1400501

How do you guys / girls work with this? I'm having a very hard time deleting photos from disk for example. On OS X, with QuickLook it's very easy to go through images on disk, in the order used in the Finder, and delete for example the blurry ones.

**Update**: It's been a while and I've learned that these kind of "questions" aren't the way to go about things, I had no right to complain, venting about existing issues doesn't help anyone.
Besides that most of these have been fixed in the mean time, fixed by people who put in the time, instead of just complained.

Answer (score 2):

When searching for Gwenview I came across Eye of Gnome (eog).
https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome
It doesn't have as many editing tools, but it also doesn't have most of the issues I ran into with Photos. (The file order is wrong, but you can open a slideshow. And you can open multiple images in the same window, which makes that less painful).

You can install it right away with Sideload: https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gnome.eog.flatpakref

Answer (score 1):

Try Gwenview instead. It's available via Softwarecenter.
Change in Setup -> Applications -> Image Viewer