# How can I delete image files using default Photos app?

Tags: photos

Elementary has nice default image viewer called Photos. But I can't understand how to delete image file in view mode. I saw "move to trash" option in main menu of this app, but I didn't see any similar option in view mode. Can you tell me hotkey for this action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, yet:
https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues/44
https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues/51

It's one of the features I'm hoping are added in the future:  [Working with photos in ElementaryOS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5587/working-with-photos-in-elementaryos)